# DSX desktop install NOT working (on x86 laptop)

Tags: x86, installation, jupyter, data-science-experience

I have tried multiple times and DSX desktop install does not work
I am trying to install on a win7 laptop

I have selected Docker, Jupyter with spark (around 6.6GB) but it always ends up installation Docker and then hangs (as in the progress bar does not proceed further and is stuck at 25% for a LONG LONG time) at installing Jupyter notebook